# Change direction of moving SKSpriteNode?

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a moving ball which is `SKSpriteNode`, and I want to change its direction alone without applying any force or impulse . When user starts touch interactions, I want the moving ball to move in the direction of touch.[image]

In the picture the ball is initially given a impulse. I don't want to change the velocity of ball but what I want is I just want to move it to right or left from its current position based on user touch. When user tap on right side of ball, the ball should bend little bit toward right and vice - versa.

**Things I Tried**

1. Applied impulse over ball in the touch direction and it caused ball to move extremely fast after few touches.
2. Applied `SKAction` `movetoPoint` method and gave my touch point to that method but it resulted in direction flip (i.e.) when ball is moving from bottom to top and if touch point is below the ball, It resulted in inverting ball direction. I Just want ball to bend along touch point without inverting its direction.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Bending" is not so easy to do. You're talking about moving the direction partially based on an arc. Also, you have to apply another impulse or force to change direction and continue movement. You can apply a speed limit in regards to #1 on things you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made to to work by making velocity to 0 when user touches began and then by applying an impulse in the direction of touch. Anyways thank you bro for your help.